# Coding to separate data from before and after last backslash when data to separate is folder path

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

Problem: There is a column that contains a folder pathway. I need to figure out how to take that column and separate the pathway from everything that follows the last backslash.

Explanation (I am also up for any advice on how to make this more automated. I'd love to make a tool that does this for those who aren't ask familiar with ArcGIS Pro to quicken their workflow) There is a consistent workflow of mine that I am trying to automate or make it simpler for others to do. We are given a KMZ (exported from .dgn if that means anything to you). To use the KMZ to the extent we need we then convert the KMZ to a layer file. However, we only care about a few specific lines that can be identified from a single column. Sadly, it is not as simple as I'd like. The identifying information is at the end of an extremely long file path. The only thing consistent about the path is that the information needed is always at the end following the last backslash. I know there has to be a way to delete or separate the data to make it simpler to identify and query the data.

Answer (score 1):

With Python, you could use Pathlib to get any part of the path structure.

```
from pathlib import Path
string_path = "folder1/folder2/folder3"
kmz_path = Path(string_path)
print(kmz_path.name)
folder3
```

You can also use the os library

```
import os
print(os.path.basename(string_path))
folder3
```

I like pathlib a little better, but both are loaded with base python.